# Cannot send POST data to Lambda using Built-in HTTPS Endpoints for Single-Function Microservices

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to send data to my AWS Lambda function however the function is not getting my data, the event variable is empty. I am not getting any errors and when I test the function in my API Gateway it works fine. So I am not sure what is happening. My code for sending data to Lambda is below.

```
curl --location 'https://.........lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws' \
--header 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "email": "value1"
}'
```

I used this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints-for-single-function-microservices/

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: " the event variable is empty" what exactly does this mean from a code perspective?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html defines the event structure.  It can't really be empty.

Comment: Do you have anything printed in the Cloudwatch logs?